# Deploy into an ArcGIS Server a map service with WMS/WFS

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, wfs

I just created an ArcGIS Server using: Windows Server 2019, IIS 10 and ArcGIS 10.9.1.

I have deployed a map document as a map service using ArcMap, and I can consume KMZ web services without any problem.

My problem is when I need to consume the WMS/WFS info for map service I deployed in my local ArcGIS Server using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3.

When importing the *.ssd file there is not way to select the type of capability of the map
[image: Pusblish service image]  and when clicking next, the sevice says: "Undefined" [image: Undefined].

It finishes with this error:
[image: ERROR 001982]

What can I do?

Comment: Are you publishing to stand-alone ArcGIS Server or a federated ArcGIS Server through Portal?

Comment: To an stand-alone ArcGIS Server

Comment: @bixb0012 I did some investigations in a another thread, and it seems that it is a Publisher role description...

Comment: It seems Publisher role is not allowed to publish GP Services after version 10.4. document link:
https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/publisher-role-support-in-manager.htm 


To add the permission for publishers, you need to follow this doc:
https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.7/administer/windows/change-geoprocessing-service-and-service-extension-publishing-privileges.htm 

I got it from https://community.esri.com/t5/publishing-and-managing-services-questions/service-publishing-error-001972/m-p/44222#M4